# Is there an expiry date on Twitch benefits?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2, red-dead-online

I just tried to get the free moonshiners upgrade and then realized I need to be at least lvl10 role to claim the benefit.

I believe it will take me a few weeks to get there. Will the benefit still be waiting for me or is there a date by which I actually have to get to lvl10 and claim it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Twitch Prime benefits do expire if not claimed by the end of the month, however, you claim them automatically upon logging into the game, even if you are not a high enough level to actually use your benefits. You may have to wait up to 72 hours after claiming them before you gain access to your benefits.

Answer (score 0):

The moment you want to claim your prize you need to have a Twitch account connected and an active subscription. After the Twitch service has expired, you will not be able to claim your prize.

Rockstar mentions this [here](https://twitch.amazon.com/prime/loot/reddeadonline) (point 10)